# Sound settings not working after login

Tags: sound, 15.04, system-settings

Up until login the sound settings in top right corner appear fine. After I login though it shows the muted icon and sound settings are all disabled. The sound plays but I can't change volume outside of what I set it at before login.

This is how it  currently looks:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmIuG.png]

Answer (score 0):

It happened exactly the same thing. In my case I had PulseAudio Equalizer installed and I just launched the equalizer and the sound was back.